# how to check if vagrant machine is running through the shell

Tags: shell, vagrant, sh, vagrantfile

I am new to Vagrant and almost new to Linux. I am practicing to learn about vagrant and so I have a vagrantfile which starts 3 machines, the first machine executes a shell script as provision method but, some the last 2 commands need to be executed just when the other 2 machines are up, so it will need to skip these commands and go back to then when the other 2 machines are up... I have gone through Vagrant documentation and I have not been able to find if this is possible to do. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: vagrant status?

Comment: how to use vagrant status to check if another machine is up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe is there a more "robust" solution, but im using:

```
vagrant status | grep "is running"
```